# How do I use Echart with English language as default in Quasar?

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, echarts, quasar-framework

As the title says. How do I do it under Quasar? I've seen this on [Echarts for React](https://github.com/hustcc/echarts-for-react/issues/156) forum. However, it doesn't work :(

[image: echart-fail]

Here's my `quasar.conf.js`,

```
build: {
  //  ...
  chainWebpack (cfg) {
    cfg.resolve.alias
      .set('echarts$', 'echarts/dist/echarts-en.min')
  }
  // ...
}
```

I was looking for something else with Quasar which already has built-in webpack.

**Notes**
I'm using `vue-echarts`

Answer (score 1):

The best thing is to set the properties manually. For example, I do this in `Angular` to set the `title` of the `saveAsImage` in the `toolbox`. Should be very similar in `Vue` for any other property.## Heading ##

```
toolbox: {
    feature: {
        saveAsImage: { title: 'Save', show: true },
    },
},
```

For your case, you need to set this

```
toolbox.feature.dataView.title = 'data view title'
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `echarts` provide API for that in [the documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#toolbox.feature.dataView.lang), and `echarts` also provides ready-use translation which you can import in `echarts/lib/langEN.js`.

All I do when initiating is this..

```
import { toolbox as features } from 'echarts/lib/langEN'

// ...some code
toolbox: {
  ...features,
  dataView: {
    show: false
  }
}
// ...some other code too
```

And the result..
[image: echart-english-result]